# How to increase the height of addView layout in webView?

Tags: android, webview

I'm new to android and making an app in which i need to increase the height of addView child layout in webView because the text appeared in the addview is cutting in height wise. please someone help m in this. Thanks

Here is the webview code:

```
question2 = new WebView(QuizActivityB.this);
// WebSettings webSettings = question2.getSettings();
// webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

// webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
// webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
question2.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
question2.getSettings().setPluginState(android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
question2.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
question2.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
question2.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
question2.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);

layout.addView(question2);
```

Comment: you need to set LayoutParams to set Height and Width.

Comment: How? can you elaborate a bit... with codes

Answer (score 0):

To Adjust or Set `Height and Width dynamically` set [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)) to the particular View and add it to the parent Layout

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.testlayout);
// create an object of your webview and set all the properties you want like background color etc.
MyWebView myWebView = new MyWebView(); 

layout.addView(myWebView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(<my_width>,<my_height>);
```

Another Option :

```
LayoutParams mParams = myWebView.getLayoutParams();
mParams.height = <my_height>;
mParams.width = <my_width>;
myWebView.setLayoutParams(mParams);
```

Comment: what is your `layout` object in `layout.addView(question2);`?

Comment: it's a relative layout declared in xml in which webview is used and sets layout to addView i.e layout.addView(question2);

Comment: @zohaib Check answer. i had changed LinearLayout to RelativeLayout